# Grunt.js - Output multiple colour theme stylesheets

Tags: automation, sass, gruntjs

I'm creating a template using SASS, and I use a variable throughout the stylesheet to dictate the primary colour of the theme.

So for example:

```
    $primaryCol : $444;
    #header { background: $primaryColour; }
    #h1 { color: $primaryColour; }
```

What I want to be able to do it, is loop through multiple variables, and output several stylesheets each with a different primary colour ($primaryCol).

So I would end up with:

```
    /css/style.css
    /css/red.css
    /css/blue.css
    /css/green.css
    ..etc..
```

This would just make my life a lot easier rather than having to go through each one, change the colour and then save it as a new file every time I want to push an update.